# Selecting multiple checkboxes from a table javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

first question here and novice programmer, i'll try to keep it simple and to the point.

In my HTML code, I have a table consisting of hundreds of rows, with a checkbox next to each one, so the user can 'select' which lines they want. I need to have it so if the user picks lines, lets say line 300 and line 400 (arbitrary numbers), lines 300-400 will all be checked. I'm not quite sure at all how to do this, my coworkers say it is possible, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: So did you ask your co-workers how? ;)

Comment: Is the user only allowed to select one contiguous range of checkboxes, or should they also have the option to select just line 300 and line 400 *without* automatically checking the lines in between?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var checkbox = $("#wrap input[type='checkbox']");
checkbox.click(function() {
  var first = $("#wrap input[type='checkbox']:checked").first().parent().index(),
    last = $("#wrap input[type='checkbox']:checked").last().parent().index(),
    length = checkbox.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (i >= first && i <= last)
      checkbox[i].checked = true;
    else
      checkbox[i].checked = false;
  }
});
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
  <span>Row <input type="checkbox" name='test'></span>
</div>
```

Comment: giving code as an without explanation will not help the user and also the future readers

Comment: Thanks @DanPhilip! I had another question if you dont mind answering.. So my code works perfectly in regards to template and such, but the checkboxes appear but don't perform the act of automatically checking between the first and last box the user checked.

Comment: My code is as follows, not sure if I am using JavaScript and HTML together correctly...
<script>**your code copy and pasted here**</script>
<div class="panel-body">
 <table width ="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
       <thead>
             <tr>
              <th>Select</th>
             </tr>
       </thead>
  <tbody>
        {%for i in bigList %}
           <tr>
             <td> <span>Select<input type="checkbox" name='test'></span> </td>
           </tr>                
        {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
 </table>

Answer (score 2):

Since your question lacks details, the only answer I can give is to create a JavaScript variable to store the first and second checkbox indices, and then perform a loop to check all the boxes in between.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using radios and not checkboxes.  And then tell the JavaScript if 2 radios are checked to get the number of those lines and then also check each one in between that range.

Comment: radios are exclusive; you should never have more than one radio in a group selected

Comment: Oh I was flip-flopped. My bad I thought he was using radios and he needed to use checkboxes.  I forgot which one was explicit and which one accepted multiples.

Comment: *"And then tell the JavaScript if 2 radios are checked to get the number of those lines and then also check each one in between that range."* - The question is *how* to "tell" JS to do that.